# java.util.Collection and java.util.Set interfaces

Tags: collections

What's the purpose of java.util.Set interface if it contains absolutely equal methods in comparison with java.util.Collection? 
There is no prohibition for multi-implementing in Java, and Set realization (HashSet) could work fine without Set interfaces. 
So why do we need that useless baggage?

Comment: there's 7 other classes that implement the interface, not just hashset  AbstractSet, ConcurrentSkipListSet, CopyOnWriteArraySet, EnumSet, JobStateReasons, LinkedHashSet, TreeSet

Comment: You're right, but nevertheless - were those classes able to implement Collection interface and forget about Set or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaDoc describing contract of [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (emphasis mine):

> A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements. **Some collections allow duplicate elements and others do not**.

On [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> A collection that **contains no duplicate elements**.

In other words, `Set` abstraction describes a (ekhem!) subset of `Collection`s.

Comment: You mean that was made to protect methods that take (Set) as an argument from passing List's realizations ?

Comment: @user2033357: that means that if you implement `Set` interface you must obey the contract (thus, don't allow duplicates). If you implement `Collection` only (not `Set`) you are free to accept duplicates. It doesn't enforce anything, it basically documents what you can accept on every implementation. If some implementation of `Set` allows duplicates, it's broken by definition.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that Collection allows duplicate elements, and Set does not. There may be more.